# Trying to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard, stuck on the Apple logo

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, install, snow-leopard

This is a weird goofy story or something. I'm trying to install Snow Leopard so I can upgrade it to Mavericks, to anyone asking; it's for nostalgia as I used to use it all the time. But this crappy problem is not letting me install it. As you see in the title, it's stuck on the Apple logo. I've tried changing the date (as I read it would install because of certificate stuff) I'm a newbie at this type of stuff and I just want to install it for nostalgia purposes.

(Also I'm using a Macbook Pro Mid-2010 15-inch.)

Comment: How are you booting? CD/DVD, USB drive, what? Does the system boot at all? What OS does it currently have? What if you boot into recovery mode (COMMAND-R_ at boot, what happens then?

Comment: USB Drive. It does. It has High Sierra. I want to dual boot it. using the recovery i tried changing the date as i said "I've tried changing the date (as i read it would install because of certificate stuff)"

Comment: Yeah, changing the date to something shortly after the release date of Snow Leopard is good. But now that I think of it Snow Leopard was a CD/DVD install disk and getting it to install from USB was a bit problematic. Can you try and burn your (presumably) DMG file to optical media and boot from that?

Comment: But I don't have a DVD/CD?????

Comment: If you're hoping to install Snow Leopard in order to get Mavericks from the app store, I have some bad news... Mavericks is not available in the app store anymore, unless you downloaded it back in the day on the same Apple ID. Instead, you'll need to try e.g. archive.org.

Comment: Are you fixated on Mavericks, which is not available from Apple? Other (earlier and later) are available from Apple - just download from one of the MrMacintosh links, make bootable installer, and install. Even if you do get 10.6.3 (or later) to install, then upgrade to 10.6.8, then I expect System Update will offer you 10.13.6 (latest supported for your MBP) as an upgrade - not Mavericks.

Comment: Snow Leopard is only installable from either a) the grey DVD which came with a 2010 MBP 15", or b) the retail 10.6.3 (or later) DVD. Are you using one of these (converted to bootable USB)?

Comment: Yes filby, also I know that mavericks isn't on the app store, I downloaded a dmg come from some goofy hackintosh site and used that dmg ever since

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably a duplicate a previously posted question.
Below are some possibilities.

- Since [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBookPro6%2C2&g-recaptcha-response=03ANYolqvh-_G_WbLPlGBHdqWzrIrZDUIcj8jSb6G7yjS4zNp-oiiwkBH5OAiPrz67APzlffYT4KB-8KHetnPeP_rfTtD8_qftkuHjiAgwk4XG-qKLuZN4gCr7-tQHtp6ZR5nDJ_tYTpPNIJsYsmUUb3hg2v23iIMu1W3uf0lEilFuQCfwm-njDGs5g_DHVeVasQ5QXIxFNaes8i1v7wchqhViweYFzHTWq8dfRP9PlnzNykXY6A5aSHXRDTcR_Q5-0ABwpL8olQmDYVyCOVED4FN5HwZ-xpk4QBkU0AO2l-3L1wH2cSuVEdZnvpsNlRdWqgwzETmKxeqZw3_kWSq_mi6JETE7MkT5Yec_xrQ9rC6viyi26kn8m50K1o0wsBzrfJxdAPBsTitmognpbC_eW-hzloAgcW9HGnPBEgE4ZCQFjzxrFWwWBLrhAFI8K8UJNMGz2PICjSHkIWOWvrXSv4QU15ywhlHnsBfUh8m7EbszUMt8-s8sgI1b0mRSTvEvD7DlR5pdExCN3IQ5XQpC2F3cHi1t-v7b9AKmuFRuTEcvL2YoCIGq2vFovPjLW3Hb-DRcV-sj-3T2VhVjNO_MMy-fhzNEq4SY0A) shows your Mac needs at least OS X 10.6.3, there is ["*Snow Leopard Clean Install"*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378302/snow-leopard-clean-install).
- There is ["*How to create a bootable OS X Snow Leopard USB drive?*"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive).

I suppose you could try installing Snow Leopard 10.6 in a VirtualBox virtual machine where the installation partition is a physical partition on your Mac. Upgrade the virtual machine to OS X 10.6.8, then try booting OS X 10.6.8 from the physical Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, I managed to find a Mac os x mavericks esd dmg and was able to install that. Sorry for the trouble