# Crash while (trying) installing Snow Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, install, snow-leopard, crash

I wanted to upgrade my old Mid-2010 13" MacBook Pro with a 500GB drive I salvaged from a slightly newer ASUS laptop with a dead GPU, and also wanted to make a sort-of downgrade (from High Sierra) back to Snow Leopard, which is the version that my MacBook Pro came with.
I flashed [this Snow Leopard ISO](https://archive.org/details/SnowLeopardInstall) onto my USB and followed [this guide (Method #3)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive#400475) to do it.

I installed the bigger hard disk, and when I plugged in the USB and booted into the Snow Leopard install disk, the MacBook [crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNNtT.jpg) in 15 seconds after selecting and loading in. Although I figured this was apparently something wrong with the USB, and not with the hard disk as I tried it again with the factory 250GB hard drive in, and saw it crash the same way.
But the MacBook still works fine when normally booting in, so that's good.

I used a 32GB Kingston DataTraveler I bought like over half a year ago for the install disk and it works just fine (still does). What do you guys think I should do?

Comment: Not sure that "flashing an ISO" is the best way to install. Apple has all the terminal commands you need to create a bootable USB key. And assuming your ISO is a legit copy should work better than the method you so briefly described. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Comment: According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html), that model came with OS X version 10.6.3, build #10D2125, which means it can only run that version & build or later. It looks like the image you got is 10.6.0, which won't work. [This](https://archive.org/details/macbook-pro-10.6.4-iso) appears to be 10.6.4, which *might* work (but it's probably a model-specific build for a different model, so maybe not). See ["Snow Leopard Clean Install"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378302).

Comment: @SteveChambers Not for Snow. The Apple Support article is for more recent OS X. Flashing an ISO is the standard way to go in this case.

Comment: Or this ISO which is explicitly 13" MBP https://archive.org/details/mac-os-x-10.6.4-13-mbp. Just have to keep on trying!

Comment: Rather than use an unverified download of Snow Leopard, I would download [the Lion disk image (.dmg) file](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683#browser) directly from Apple. You can use [OS X/macOS](https://maclinks.publicvm.com/makebootable.html#content4-3y) or [Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460708/macbook-air-2011-cannot-boot-from-usb/460763#460763) to create an USB bootable Lion installer from this download.